# Use Set Collection as a member of my Questions Class

Tags: java

I want to use Set Collection as a member of my Questions Class for storing unique multiple amswers

```
class Questions
{
   int id ;
   String question;
   Set<String> answers ;
}
```

But Don't know how to store answers and retrieve them from it
Can anybody help me by providing relevant example?

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a class instance and get and set the  value of instance variables?

Comment: Do you mean how to map which are the answers to a particular question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Questions class:**

```
class Questions {

  private int id;
  private String question;
  private Set<String> answers;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
  }

  public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
  }

  public Set<String> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
  }

  public void setAnswers(Set<String> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
  }

}
```

**Sample:**

```
public class Sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Questions question = new Questions();
    question.setId(101);
    question.setQuestion("Random Question");

    Set<String> answer= new HashSet<String>();
    answer.add("random answer1");
    answer.add("random answer2");

    question.setAnswers(answer);

    //Similarly invoke getXXX to get the values
  }

}
```